# Are there fixed volume spouts / valves?

Tags: plumbing, valve, spout

I am looking for a spout or valve that always dispenses a fixed volume / opens for a fixed time. The idea is to install it on a tank so that you can press a button, it dispenses 400 ml of water / runs for 10 seconds and then closes automatically.

I've tried finding some but so far to no avail. Do spouts / valves like this exist and if so, what are they called?

Comment: Something as a "self closing push button shower valve"?

Comment: What is the pressure, if you have several pounds of pressure a solenoid valve will work with a timing circuit.

Answer (score 3):

- There are faucets, often found in commercial settings, where you push the lever down and it runs for a fixed amount of time. These are installed to ensure the water is turned off instead of someone walking out and leaving it running. They may be adjustable for run time, or you may find that it works for you right out of the box. Try a plumbing supply house, not a big-box store to see what's available.
- You could use some sort of smart home setup. Have a smart button with one action - open a valve for `x` seconds, then close it. Optionally, have it turn on power for a pump that runs, pushing water out of an *unvalved* faucet for `x` seconds then shuts off. (May end up with some water -between the pump & outlet- dripping for a few seconds, might be inconvenient.)
- Stop by your local plumbing supply house to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the terminology for this style of faucet is "[Metering Faucet](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=metering%20faucet)".

Answer (score 0):

Ridiculous option #1: Toilet flush.
I do not know if you can find a tiny one or regulate existing one to exact volume you request, but they are cheap and commonly available. The standard modern volume is 3 liters, but they have regulation. Perhaps you can DIY hack one to dispense half a liter for you. Ask in plumbing store for tiniest one, or one with smallest base.

Option 2 - also toilet equipment - a push button valve commonly used on urinals.

It also depend whether you need potable water or technical water - above are most likely not rated for potable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure these exist for laboratory/manufacturing use. Whether there's anything affordable is something if a shopping question. Hit lab supply catalogs?

Comment: An example is the deeterflow liquid volume dispenser. It's a specialized area for sure.

Comment: Ditto medical infusion pumps, though at much smaller volumes over longer times.  I had a job that, among other things, involved testing, calibrating, and repairing  those during my break year before college.

Answer (score 0):

You want a time delay relay supplying a solenoid valve's operating voltage. Irrigation equipment uses 24V AC, but depending on your supply pressure and flow rate, you may want a different solenoid valve. [This time delay relay](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BFRPMNK3), for example, would fulfill your use case if it satisfies the voltage and amperage specs of your solenoid valve.